# Docker container exits on non-zero exit status

Tags: docker

I have a Docker image whose `CMD` is `/bin/bash` to allow user interaction with tools contained within. I'm having an issue where if a command run on the bash prompt exits with a non-zero exit status -- e.g. `$ badcmd` -- the container exits. I'd like to be able to execute multiple commands in the container, keeping it open even if a specific command fails.

My `run` command is:

```
docker run --rm -it <image>
```

I've tried adding `--sig-proxy=false`, but as it states in the help message, that works on non-TTY mode only.

Additionally, I tried:

```
docker run --rm -i --sig-proxy=false <image>
```

This get's me slightly closer, but not in a really usable way as it allows for shell interaction, but omit's the bash prompt -- which while functional, it's really viable.

Docker version info:

```
Client version: 1.5.0
Client API version: 1.17
Go version (client): go1.4.1
Git commit (client): a8a31ef
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.5.0
Server API version: 1.17
Go version (server): go1.4.1
Git commit (server): a8a31ef
```

Thanks for any help!

Cheers,
J

Comment: This does not happen for me when using the `ubuntu:14.04` image on Docker 1.4.1.  Does your image define a `.bashrc` that does `set -e`?

Comment: It's so simple I didn't even think to look for it. I was sourcing a script that did in fact contain `set -e`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be because of a `set -e` in a script that was being sourced in the `.bashrc`. Thanks @jwodder!